# Is It possible to Remove particular browser history

Tags: javascript, jquery

Because of some requirement, Calling of My pages is like

```
/url/home

/url/page1

/url/page1?abc=1

/url/page1?abc=2
```

As a result when i click on browserback from "/url/page1?abc=2", it goes to "
/url/page1?abc=1" and so on.

I want when i click  browserback from "/url/page1?abc=2" it should go stright to "/url/home", So i wanted to remove 2 urls "/url/page1" & /url/page1?abc=1" from history.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

you can use this one instead of removing browser history

`window.location.replace(URL);`

> It will replace the current document with the one at the provided URL.

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location